# Failed to decode image while using Image.memory flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im using this function to get image from url as Unit8List.

the problem is when i run the code it has this error:

E/FlutterJNI(26939): Failed to decode image
E/FlutterJNI(26939): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
E/FlutterJNI(26939):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.nCreate(Native Method)
E/FlutterJNI(26939):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.access$200(ImageDecoder.java:173)
E/FlutterJNI(26939):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ByteBufferSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:250)
E/FlutterJNI(26939):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmapImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1847)
E/FlutterJNI(26939):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.java:1840)
E/FlutterJNI(26939):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.decodeImage(FlutterJNI.java:514)

```
Future<dynamic> getImage() async {
    late Uint8List bytes;
    try {
      final ByteData imageData =
          await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse('some link'))
              .load("");
      bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
      print(bytes);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return bytes;
  }
```

in ui code i used FutureBuilder to get data, then i used Image.memory to show image from url.

```
 return FutureBuilder(
      future: Get.find<Networking>().getImage(widget.imageUrl),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return LoadingAnimationWidget.threeArchedCircle(
              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, size: 40);
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            Get.showSnackbar(const GetSnackBar(
                title: 'Error', message: 'something wents wrong'));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                child:snapshot.data != null ? SizedBox(
                            height: 110,
                            child: Image.memory(snapshot.data!, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    Object object, StackTrace? stack) {
                              return const Center(child: Text('No image'));
                            })) :  const Center(child: Text('No image')),
               ),
            );
          }
        }
        return SizedBox(
          height: Get.height * 0.7,
          child: const Center(
              child: Text('Nothing found!',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black))),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Can you send me the URL for the picture that doesn't work for you? It seems it's working for me now. I have an answer for you but I want to double-check your URL before pasting my answer.